# Best constant for Sobolev-type inequality

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces, calculus-of-variations

I am currently reading a paper from Del Pino/Dolbeault about optimal constants of GNS inequalities (http://capde.cmm.uchile.cl/files/2015/06/pino2002.pdf).

The author wants to prove the following GNS inequality:
$$\lVert w\rVert_{2p}\leq A\lVert \nabla w\rVert_{2}^{\theta}\lVert w\rVert_{p+1}^{1-\theta},$$
where $\theta$ is given and $A$ is the best possible constant.

In order to prove this, he states another theorem (Theorem 4 in the paper), which is actually equivalent to the theorem involving the GNS inequality above. This theorem now is about minimization of a certain linear functional with an additional constraint. The linear functional is: $$G(w)=\frac{1}{2}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}|\nabla w|^2dx+\frac{1}{p+1}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}|w|^{p+1}dx$$ and the integral constraint is: $$\frac{1}{2p}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}|w|^{2p}dx=J_{\infty},$$ where $J_{\infty}$ is given.

The proof of this theorem and the way it implies the GNS inequality are fine for me.

My question is rather why exactly the author wants to minimize the above linear functional in a first place. Why exactly this approach? I know that it is hard to guess what someone else was thinking, but maybe someone can explain me the intuition behind this idea. What does the above GNS inequality have to do with the minimization of $G(w)$?

Is this kind of argument also helpful in order to prove other type of inequalities or does this only work here?

Comment: I think this is a common trick. The point is that it's easier to study the linear (semilinear) problem associated to G. On the other hand, the multiplicative and additive estimates are essentially equivalent, thanks to AM-GM and scaling. You might try to check for yourself that if you know the sharp GNS inequality, then AM-GM gives you the sharp estimate for G. Conversely, you can use the scaling trick in the proof of GNS in the paper you link to go from the linear to the multiplicative (this is the direction which is more surprising, I think, but the paper explains it very nicely).

Comment: I know this trick is used in many places, but I don't know of a good reference off the top of my head. The book of Lieb and Loss has many such results but maybe you are already familiar with this.